# Extra gap added to figure elements in grid layout

Tags: html, css, figure, css-grid

I see extra space added to grid elements, causing misalignment of elements but can’t figure out where it is coming from (margins, padding for elements are nullified, grid elements align to start vertically and horizontally).

EDIT: I tried to limit the wrapper size to 820x410, which does eliminate the gaps. I do understand grid columns are stretched to fill the wrapper div. While this handles the problem I still do not understand where extra vertical gaps are coming from.

[image: pixel perfect images inside figure elements]

**Styles:**

```
#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    justify-items: start;
    align-items: start;
}
#wrapper * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
figure {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: 0;
}
figure img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 860px;
}
#wrapper>figure:first-child {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <figure id="element1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x410" />
    </figure>
    <figure id="element2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </figure>
    <figure id="element3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </figure>
    <figure id="element4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </figure>
    <figure id="element5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `width: 100%` in your `img`.

Why?

Because your wrapper is `860px` and you have 2 columns, equally divided, with a `grid-gap` of `10px` so each column will have `420px` + `10px` from the `grid-gap` horizontal, making a total of `430px`, but your image only is `400px` wide therefore you have 20px of space in your left column and 10px in your right column because it is divided in two small columns of `210px`

There go your solution is to apply the `width:100%` in `img` to always fill the column and `height:100%` (if you want to use responsive like my code bellow)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px
}

#wrapper * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  border: 1px dotted red
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 860px;
}

#wrapper>figure:first-child {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <figure id="element1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x410" />
  </figure>
  <figure id="element2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </figure>
  <figure id="element3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </figure>
  <figure id="element4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </figure>
  <figure id="element5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not handle extra vertical gaps though.

Comment: Looking at this more carefully, the top row of the smaller images is scaled up (have different height than the bottom row). Could you elaborate why this is happening and what could be the solution? Try to remove image scaling and adjust the #wrapper constraints. The way I see it is to remove row-gap altogether and add padding to #element2 and #element3. I want to achieve equal gaps inside, no gaps outside and the whole set of images responsive.